# PHP won't output new line

Tags: php

I've tried every method to output a newline in PHP. Why doesn't the following work? :

```
<?php

$foo = 'bar'; 
echo "Hello \n $foo!";

?>
```

This should output a newline between hello and bar but it isn't.

I also tried \r\n instead of \n

Comment: A newline doesn't mean anything ***in HTML***.

Comment: @deceze Technically it should be the same as a space.

Comment: @NoBugs OK, "not anything" is not quite correct... :)

Comment: Guys, I understand this is a stupid question, obviously the asker didn't try googling it. But down-vote? Why? Code + question is a solid question. Doesn't deserve a down-vote. Be nice, answer the question with the correct answer and "Try googling next time"

Comment: I think people are encouraged to downvote because when you hover over the downvote button it states *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*

Comment: @Henry SO is (at least partly) supposed to be a database of programming problems *which are not readily answered everywhere else.* This problem here is one of the first things one should come across following any tutorial for HTML. We do not want this to clog up search results when you search for a real problem. Hence, downvote.

Comment: @deceze Good point. I guess it is just a personal thing. I was once in this guys shoes and I wish more SO users just replied with a quick comment like, try googling or something before asking on SO instead of dishing out down-votes to questions that are legitimate questions without the user understanding what he did wrong.

Comment: @HenryHarris or `she`. Can't leave the ladies out ;-)

Comment: @Fred Ha. Sorry for the .001% of stack users left out. ;)

Comment: @HenryHarris there are actual `stats`? lol - one never knows one's `gender` if the obvious starts off like Bob, Larry, Curly or Moe. It's those `user*****` that you have to start wondering about!

Comment: @fred haha. just going by odds `he` is a safe bet. ;)

Comment: @user24... BTW, welcome to SO. Just, please, show some more initiative the next time. Following a decent basic tutorial or book for the topic at hand is the least one is expected to do before dropping a question.

Comment: @HenryHarris Indeed ;-) However, boats are all `SHEs`. Now that's completely off-topic, but just as much fun! cheers

Comment: Do you have PHP 7.0 installed and are on a Windows machine? Use "<br>";

Answer (score 11):

If you using it as command line script this would work. I would use `PHP_EOL` for this since it chooses the right line break for the OS.

However if you are working with HTML (viewing the result in browser for example) you have to use the HTML way of linebreaks which is: `<br />`

Comment: U helped me a lot.

Answer (score 7):

To output a new line in HTML you need to use HTML's representation of a new line which is `<br/>`

php has a function for you that converts all natural new lines to HTML new lines > `nl2br()`

Then your code should look like

```
<?php

$foo = 'bar'; 
echo nl2br("Hello \n $foo!");

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `<br>` when inserting line break in html

Comment: thanks, just did that

Comment: @user2463517 Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please choose your accepted answer using the check mark under the voting totals to the left of the answer you choose.

Answer (score 3):

To output a new line visually (in a browser), you need `HTML`:

```
echo "Hello\n<br />$foo!";
```

`\n` is a system line feed.

Comment: This is only when opening a website using PHP. PHP can be executed in console. For console, his code will run just fine. For webpages, you code will run ok.

Comment: To clarify, to output a new line using a program that renders HTML (i.e. a browser), you need HTML.  If you're outputting a new line visually, like in a file or elsewhere, you might want a carriage return and line feed.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Using 99% certainty in guessing they are outputting this in a browser.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed the same. I commented only as reference ;)

Comment: On command line this ur code return 2x new line. Better to use on `\n` or `<br>` or best `nl2br($str . PHP_EOL);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$foo = 'bar'; 
echo "Hello <br> $foo!";,

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you view the source you will see it actually DOES have a new line in it, But white space doesnt matter in HTML (what the browser displaying the output is expecting) but adding a `<br />` to your statement will produce a new line because this is the way browsers read new lines and display them.