# PHP newline character not being recognized from Nano text editor

Tags: php, newline

I have set up a small web server using my Raspberry Pi SOC, and I am currently writing some PHP code to be displayed in the browser using the Nano text editor.

I wish to have my code separated on new lines, but the newline characters I have tried (PHP_EOL and "\n") within the Nano text editor don't seem to be recognized when opening the binary.php file from the browser. Below I have screenshots of the PHP source code and the current display from the browser.

Any thoughts?

[PHP source code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McR7y.jpg)[Display of binary.php in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMWux.jpg)

Comment: This has nothing to do with nano. The newline character has no meaning in HTML.

Comment: Browsers do not process new lines. You'll need to use `<br />`. New lines are for non-browser output, such as text files and the console.

Comment: if you don't need html, than you can change the content-type to text like `header("Content-type: text/plain);`. otherwise replace `\n` with `<br>`

Comment: I'm able to add HTML code within the binary.php file? I added the line break and now my file won't open in browser..

Comment: Show your code with the line break. Remember that it's text and not a PHP global, so it needs to be within the quotes.

Comment: I added quotes around the line break and it worked. I appreciate the help everyone! Learning more and more each day..

Comment: did you try printf "\n";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP won't output new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991841/php-wont-output-new-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - how to create a newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the

```
<br/>
```

character instead